# The textbox value assigned at server side is not getting rendered in ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, telerik

We have an aspx page built using Telerik controls, on a dropdown selected index change event at the server side, we are assigning a value to a textbox, but when the page is viewed the textbox value is not shown.

Code used:

```
Protected Sub Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.WebControls.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles dropdown.SelectedIndexChanged 

   txtCost.Text = finalcost.ToString() 
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alert", "OpenModelPopup();", True)

End Sub
```

Comment: Show us some code then, can only make guesses as to what this is until you do. (Could be that you need to wrap some page load code in a postback check, or that you're not handling the index changed event correctly).

Comment: after the selcted index change event is done. the control goes to the page load events. but we have put a boolean check where these page events avoid any execution.

Comment: Protected Sub Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.WebControls.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles dropdown.SelectedIndexChanged txtCost.Text = finalcost.ToString()  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alert", "OpenModelPopup();", True)

Comment: the page.clientscript method is used to call a script function in client side to display the popup div which contains the dropdown and the textbox.

Comment: How is the Dropdown defined in the .aspx file?